# Passing arguments to extended keras.model without init

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[keras](/questions/tagged/keras) documentation provides an [example](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/) of extending the [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model without the `init` method. From my understanding, this is nice because you don't have to implement the `call` function. Now to instantiate the model you can do something like this

```
model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)
```

Not sure where `inputs`, `outputs` are going - it would be nice to know - but my question is how to do I pass additional arguments when instantiating the model i.e.:

```
 model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs, other_args)
```

**Edit**

`other_args` can be anything passed to `CustomModel` (not `keras.model`) i.e.: `alpha=1.0`

The research effort is that I looked through keras documentation and it shows two ways to extend the model. The advertised method is to implement `__init__`

Comment: @M.Innat   The question is clear - It even has an accepted answer below. When you extend the keras model you have to implement the init-method. However, I showed an example from the docs where you do not have to implement the init. So - my question is how do we pass args without the init per example in keras docs. What is unclear about this?

Comment: By the way - for "the community" an alternative to the accepted answer is to create a setter and call it before compile.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question, that's not our style. Apart from that, please edit your question; define `other_args`, and include your research effort on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CustomModel example allows one to override specific methods of the Model class (`train_step`) in the example.
When you call

```
model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)
```

inputs is a tensor or list of input tensors to the custom model and outputs the output tensor(s).

You can see that in the example:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)
```

This defines a graph with an input layer with shape (32,) and a single output neuron (and no hidden layers).

Please clarify the usage of `other_args`. If these are tensors used by the model train / fit they should be part of the input / output arguments (which can be a list of tensors). If `other_args` are parameters that influence the Model custom `train_step` function then you need to define a new **init** method that expects it and call `super().__init__(inputs, outputs)`.

The `keras.Model` class is concerned with the machinery of training and predicting models. The ML model itself is defined as a graph of keras.Layer(s).